# Scale rows of 3D-tensor

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have an `n`-by-`3`-by-`3` numpy array `A` and an `n`-by-`3` numpy array `B`. I'd now like to multiply every *row* of every one of the `n` `3`-by-`3` matrices with the corresponding scalar in `B`, i.e.,

```
import numpy as np

A = np.random.rand(10, 3, 3)
B = np.random.rand(10, 3)

for a, b in zip(A, B):
    a = (a.T * b).T
    print(a)
```

Can this be done without the loop as well?

Comment: Aha! I've always used the `.T`-`.T` dance for row scaling, but this one is actually better. If you promote the comment to an answer, I'll be happy to mark it a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`NumPy broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to let the elementwise multiplication happen in a vectorized manner after extending `B` to `3D` after adding a singleton dimension at the end with `np.newaxis` or its alias/shorthand `None`. Thus, the implementation would be `A*B[:,:,None]` or simply `A*B[...,None]`.